# Using prepared statements with mysql in python

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to use SQL with prepared statements in Python.  Python doesn't have its own mechanism for this so I try to use SQL directly:

```
sql = "PREPARE stmt FROM ' INSERT INTO {} (date, time, tag, power) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)'".format(self.db_scan_table)
self.cursor.execute(sql)
```

Then later, in the loop:

```
sql = "EXECUTE stmt USING \'{}\', \'{}\', {}, {};".format(d, t, tag, power)
self.cursor.execute(sql)
```

And in the loop I get:

```
MySQL Error [1064]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''2014-12-25', '12:31:46', 88000000, -6.64' at line 1
```

What's going on?

Comment: You are just formatting the query yourself, and doing it wrong. Mysql complains about two adjacent single quotes.

Comment: @newtover - Yes, I am formatting the query myself.  Which part am I doing wrong?

Comment: The method execute expects a formatting string and parameters.

Comment: An interesting question is, why you want to use prepared statements in the first place.

Comment: @newtover - I am under the impression that using prepared statements gives you a more efficient binary connection to the mysql server, in contrast to a regular 'insert' done over and over again in a loop.

Comment: Not so straightforward: http://www.percona.com/blog/2006/08/02/mysql-prepared-statements/. You can hardly save on skipping binary conversion using the python db api, and you need to close them.

Comment: @horsehair, sure, but when you call the two-arguments form of `execute` (or `executemany`), the `MySQLdb` module (which knows all about efficiency:-) internally does the `PREPARE` (only once per SQL-with-placeholders string, then the prepared-statement object is cached in a dict with the string as the key) and (once or more) the `EXECUTE`.

Comment: @AlexMartelli: Could you point to where in the source code (for MySQLdb) this caching occurs?

Comment: @AlexMartelli: It looks like in cursor.py's `BaseCursor.execute` the `query` is getting string interpolated with the `args` very early on, leaving no chance for a cached prepared-statement object.

Comment: @unutbu -- you're right, it's `Connector/Python` (now preferred according to the mysql.com official site) that actually guarantees using prepared statements, per http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursorprepared.html -- and it wants you to be slightly explicit about it, using a `.cursor(prepared=True)` to make the cursor.  We've done lots of experimenting internally on `mysqldb` over the years (open-sourcing only the experiments that worked out right!-) and I suspect the automatic use of prepared statements was an experiment that didn't quite work well:-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using prepared statements with MySQL in Python is explained e.g at http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlpython/ -- look within that page for `Prepared statements`.

In your case, that would be, e.g:

```
sql = ('INSERT INTO {} (date, time, tag, power) VALUES '
       '(%s, %s, %s, %s)'.format(self.db_scan_table))
```

and later, "in the loop" as you put it:

```
self.cursor.execute(sql, (d, t, tag, power))
```

with no further string formatting -- the `MySQLdb` module does the prepare and execute parts on your behalf (and may cache things to avoid repeating work needlessly, etc, etc).

Do consider, depending on the nature of "the loop" you mention, that it's possible that a single call to `.execute_many` (with a sequence of tuples as the second argument) could take the place of the whole loop (unless you need more processing within that loop beyond just the insertion of data into the DB).

Added: a better alternative nowadays may be to use mysql's own `Connector/Python` and the explicit `prepare=True` option in the `.cursor()` factory -- see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursorprepared.html .  This lets you have a specific cursor on which statements are prepared (with the "more efficient than using PREPARE and EXECUTE" binary protocol, according to that mysql.com page) and another one for statements that are better not prepared; "explicit is better than implicit" **is** after all one of the principles in "The Zen of Python" (`import this` from an interactive prompt to read all those principles).  `mysqldb` doing things implicitly (and it seems the current open-source version **doesn't** use prepared statements) can't be as good an architecture as `Connector/Python`'s more explicit one.

Comment: The loop is needed because the data is continually generated from an external source.

Comment: @horsehair, depending on circumstances it may still be possible to chunk up the data coming from the external source and do an `executemany` on a chunk at a time.  However this optimization is minor unless your latency to the DB is high, so `execute` is probably going to be OK anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the good info.  Should I db.commit() after every insert or only after the thread is terminated?

Comment: If every insert is stand-alone (i.e, you don't need atomic behavior whereby either all or none of your inserts occur), keeping transactions short is preferable.  Unless multi-statement atomic transactions are needed somewhere, connecting with `autocommit=True` from the start may in fact be better (then, of course, you don't bother calling `commit` at all:-).

Comment: The linked zetcode tutorial does not show an example of [Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-stmt-execute.html). The tutorial shows an example of a Parameterized Query but calls it a Prepared Statement.

Comment: It's `prepared=True`.

Answer (score 4):

```
        import mysql.connector
        db_con=mysql.connector.connect(host='',
            database='',
            user='',
            password='')

        cursor = db_con.cursor(prepared=True,)
        #cursor = db_con.cursor(prepared=True)#IT MAY HAVE PROBLEM

        sql = """INSERT INTO table (xy,zy) VALUES (%s, %s)"""
        input=(1,2)
        cursor.execute(sql , input)
        db_con.commit()
```

SELECT STMT

```
        sql = """SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE XY=%s ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 """
        ID=1

        input=(ID,)
        #input=(ID)# IT MAY HAS PROBLEM
        cursor.execute(sql, input)
        data = cursor.fetchall()
        rowsNumber=cursor.rowcount
```

Answer (score 1):

Python does support prepared statements:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO {} (date, time, tag, power) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s);"
sql = sql.format(self.db_scan_table)
self.cursor.execute(sql, (d, t, tag, power))
```

(You should ensure `self.db_scan_table` is not vulnerable to SQL injection)

This assumes your [`paramstyle`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle) is `'format'`, which it [should be for MySQL](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#functions-and-attributes).

Comment: This is not a prapared statement.

Comment: Yes it is -- again, as per my answer, see http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlpython/ at **Prepared statements**.  The prepared-statement object is handled internally by `MySQLdb` (in a cache keyed by the textual SQL thus prepared).

Comment: @AlexMartelli, I agree, that mysql-python does most of the things for which prepared statements are usually used. But they are still not the same.

Comment: Right -- you might use `Connector/Python` if you need to make sure prepared statements are being used "behind the curtains", see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursorprepared.html ; with good old `mysqldb`, you can't be quite sure what's happening behind said curtains.

Comment: Looking at mysqldb's source code [1.2.4b4](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/files/) reveals, that it doesn't use prepared statements, just string formatting.