# Python mysql statement returning error when called from php

Tags: php, python, mysql, csv, exec

I have a python script which takes csv as an input and insert its data to Database. and I am calling this script from a php script where I am generating this CSV. If I call python script from terminal and pass csv to it, it works perfectly but if I call it from php using

```
exec('python bulk_metadata_ingest_dev.py '. $metadataCSV);
```

It throws a mysql error while inserting to a table.

**_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'text to insert""\' at line 1')**

Query which throwing this error :

```
cursor = db.query("insert into test_table(asset_type, attribute_id, asset_title, is_publishable, owner) values(\""+str(mediaAssetTypeDict[sample_content.media_type.lower()])+"\", \""+str(attributeId)+"\", \""+str(assetTitle)+"\", \""+str(publishAssets)+"\", \""+str(sample_content.content_owner)+"\" )")
```

In python I don't know how to handle this problem. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: shouldn't \"" be \"\" ? Just a wild guess.

Comment: what are the values in you insert data?

Comment: Interesting question by @antonio_antuan and what if you reduce the need to escape by using instead `cursor = db.query("insert into test_table(asset_type, attribute_id, asset_title, is_publishable, owner) values('"+str(mediaAssetTypeDict[sample_content.media_type.lower()])+"', '"+str(attributeId)+"', '"+str(assetTitle)+"', '"+str(publishAssets)+"', '"+str(sample_content.content_owner)+"')")` ? I know databases, that do not like double quotes around string literals ...

Comment: @Dilettant Thanks man It worked. But its still a mystery for me why this python script works fine when I run it directly from terminal with the same input file.

Comment: If I had "such a task" of write from a python script into a database, I would next simplify and secure the proxy a bit, i.e. try a prepared statement, not construct the string to "query" inside the parentheses of the call operator, but maybe build a tuple and then fill in the "blanks" of the prepared statement. This reduces the many layered single quote, double quote string call onion skins, is more explicit, does not smell like presentation state manipulations and is more safe, when accepting input from outside a boundary of trust. But good it now let's you continue. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: One last comment (in the hope it helps): If you do the switch to prepared statements with mysql and python there are good pages to turn to, e.g. [Using prepared statements with mysql in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27649759/using-prepared-statements-with-mysql-in-python) was the first I came across

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using a mySQL reserved word `OWNER` as a column name in your table and not using backticks. Try changing your select to:

```
...("insert into test_table(asset_type, attribute_id, asset_title, is_publishable, `owner`")... 
                                                                                   ^     ^
```

Check out [Table 9.2](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) in the docs for a complete list.