# Uploading image to mariadb database

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb, blob

I'm new to sql so maybe this is just a beginner's mistake, but after trying some solutions I found here and there I'm still unable to solve this problem. I'm trying to upload an image to a mariadb database through a python script which looks like this:

```py
import mysql.connector
path=input("File to upload: ")
with open(path,'rb') as f:
 fileData=f.read()
query=f"UPDATE emp SET image={fileData} WHERE empId=1;"
db=mysql.connector.connect(...)
myCursor=db.cursor()
myCursor.execute(query)
myCursor.close()
db.close()
print(f"Uploaded {path} to the database...")
```

However, when the code reaches `myCursor.execute(query)` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "webSqlSampleClient.py", line 16, in <module>
    myCursor.execute(query)
  File "/home/asriel/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 551, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "/home/asriel/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 490, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "/home/asriel/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 395, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\xff\xe1\x00'' at line 1
```

What's wrong with my code? The rest of the query seems correct as I've used the very same `UPDATE` statement with other non-image values successfully.
Thank you in advance for the help.

-Update:

As @tadman suggested, I've used %s as a placeholder in my sql query, so the new code looks like this:

```py
query="UPDATE emp SET image=%s WHERE empId=1"
db=mysql.connector.connect(...)
myCursor=db.cursor()
myCursor.execute(query, (fileData,))
myCursor.close()
db.close()
```

The code above doesn't run into any exceptions and prints the intended output, however, when I execute the following SQL statement in my SQL client:

```sql
SELECT image 
FROM emp 
WHERE empId = 1;
```

it says that the value for image is `NULL`.

What's wrong now? `image` is a blob, in case that's not clear.

Comment: I think using prepared statements can solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27649874/8543203

Comment: You have a placeholder value you didn't bind. `{...}` is not valid SQL notation.

Comment: Note: `;` is a SQL statement delimiter used in interactive shells. It does not need to be, nor should be specified in a context like this where the statement end is the end of the string.

Comment: @tadman ```{}``` has nothing to do with the sql query, but with python formatting with f strings, so in theory it should be valid. I didn't know that ```;``` wasn't compulsory in this context though, I'll count with that from now on, thanks.

Comment: If that's the case than that is absolutely not valid. You can't just jam binary data into the middle of the query and expect it to work. You need to use *placeholder values*, which with Python's default MySQL driver is `%s`, then `execute(query, (fileData,))` to bind it.

Comment: Does `{fileData}` get "escaped"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've just got it to work:
the answer I used to solve the first problem was @tadman's answer (which is in the question's comments). The problem I had with the database not updating its values was solved by adding `db.commit()` (I forgot that, silly mistake). Thanks for all of your helpful comments anyways!