# Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' and I cannot use auto_increment since the values do not always increase

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

**What I am trying to do**

I have been trying to insert a record to a table via tkinter, and I want to see the inserted record on mysql.

**Issue

 After entering a record to tkinter, I received the following error. I looked into the solutions for the same errors posted online, but it was to use auto_increment for column Code (the one with primary key). However, I cannot use auto_increment since the values of the column Code does not always increase. I have also tried deleting primary key for the column but I still got the same error. Any insights on this?**

**Error:**

*mysql.connector.errors.IntegrityError: 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'*

**Code to create the table:**

```
#table
cursor=mycon.cursor(buffered=True)
cursor.execute("use iv")
cursor.execute("drop table if exists salesperson")
create_table='''create table salesperson
(
code int(4) primary key,
name varchar(15),
salary int,
itcode char
)'''
cursor.execute(create_table)
```

**Code to insert data to mysql from tkinter/python:**

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo

def add_data():
    code=tcode.get('1.0',END) #retrieve input
    name=tname.get('1.0',END)
    salary=tsal.get('1.0',END)
    itcode=titcode.get('1.0',END)

    #DATABASE CONNECTION
    if code=="" or name=="" or salary=="" or itcode=="":
        messagbox.showinfo("Please fill all the fields")
    else:
        import mysql.connector as sqltor
        connection=sqltor.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="  ",database="iv")
        tkcursor=connection.cursor()
        tkcursor.execute("Insert into salesperson values (code,'name',salary,'itcode')")
        connection.commit()
        messagebox.showinfo("Records inserted")
        tkcursor.close()
```

Comment: Have you tried `print(code)` to verify, it is what your expecting? and not a duplicate of what was there previously

Comment: please use prepared statemente with parameters see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27649759/using-prepared-statements-with-mysql-in-python

Comment: Thank you for reaching out. While I don't quite I understand where to execute **print(code)**, I inserted a record that was not a duplicate of any other records' values.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the INSERT statement:

```
tkcursor.execute("Insert into salesperson values (code,'name',salary,'itcode')")
```

When you reference an identifier in an SQL statement like this, it's an SQL identifier, not a Python variable. It's not an error in this case because your table coincidentally has columns named `code` and `salary`.

But what is the value of these columns? Since this is an INSERT statement, by definition the row doesn't exist yet as the VALUES() clause is evaluated. So the value of all columns of that row is NULL. It's exactly as if you had done this:

```
tkcursor.execute("Insert into salesperson values (NULL,'name',NULL,'itcode')")
```

Since `code` is the primary key, it must be NOT NULL. Even though the column does not have a DEFAULT defined, MySQL has a concept of a "default default." That is, in absence of an explicitly defined default value, each data type will be converted to an appropriate implicit default value if NULL is not accepted (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html for documentation on this). For an integer, the implicit default is 0. So your statement works as if you did this:

```
tkcursor.execute("Insert into salesperson values (0,'name',NULL,'itcode')")
```

How to fix this? You should use parameters to help you get the values of your Python variables into your SQL INSERT statement. That way the Python variable `code` will be used, not the SQL column that is also named `code`. The comment above from nbk hinted at this.

```
tkcursor=connection.cursor(prepared=True)
tkcursor.execute("Insert into salesperson values (%s,'name',%s,'itcode')", (code, salary,)
connection.commit()
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursorprepared.html for more information.

Comment: So in a nutshell, what does `prepared` do?

Comment: It allows the use of placeholders in your SQL query (`%s`) that you can combine with application variables. It's safer that simple string substitution or `.format()` because it accounts for things like if the variables have literal quote characters in them, or there are character set differences. It's a good habit to use parameters to combine variables with SQL statements. It makes your queries safe from SQL injection, and it's easier to write the code.

Comment: But I have done the same without any `prepared` argument. So its not necessary to say `prepared` I guess?

Comment: Thank you for reaching out with a detailed answer. But even after executing your suggested code, I received an error: *Data too long for column 'itcode' at row 1*  Any insights on this?

Comment: That's a separate issue. You declared `itcode` as the type `char`. If you don't give a length, what is the default length limit for `char`? The default is as if you had declared it as `char(1)`. So it only allows strings of 1 character. You will get that error if you try to store a string longer than 1 character. You either need to ensure that your Python variable `itcode` is 1 character, or else declare the column to store longer strings.